# Method name conventions in Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Is there a list of what conventions are used in Web API 2?

Take these two methods for example. Both work, neither are decorated with attributes.

```
IHttpActionResult GetMyModel(int id)

IEnumerable<MyModel> GetAllMyModels()
```

`Get` responds to the route "{controller}/{action}/{id}", so I assume `GetAllMyModels` works because of its return type? Or the `GetAll` prefix?

Are there other conventions?

On a related note, why does `GetAllMyModels` return an enumerable while `GetMyModel` returns the `MyModel` in the `IHttpActionResult`? Should I have returned `IHttpActionResult` from `GetAllMyModels`?

Comment: I really doubt this is not already well-documented on the internet. What have you found so far?

Comment: If the method's name starts with `Get`, then the `GET` HTTP verb will use it - depending on what parameters it needs to pass to the method, it'll pick the most appropriate one

Comment: Focus specifically on the GetAll convention. I appreciate it is using Get here, but obviously GetAll isn't an HTTP verb, so I'm assuming it's either matching on signature or method name.

Comment: Jim, I'm sure it's described in depth on a thousand pages, none of which have been served up to me by Google. How about contributing one of them instead of making snarky comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the name of a method starts with a defined HTTP Method it will be mapped to that method in the absence of a specific attribute definition.

```
private static Collection<HttpMethod> GetSupportedHttpMethods()
```

in `System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor` uses `_supportedHttpMethodsByConvention`

```
private static readonly HttpMethod[] _supportedHttpMethodsByConvention = 
{ 
    HttpMethod.Get, 
    HttpMethod.Post, 
    HttpMethod.Put, 
    HttpMethod.Delete, 
    HttpMethod.Head, 
    HttpMethod.Options, 
    new HttpMethod("PATCH") 
};
```

<snip/>

```
// Get HttpMethod from method name convention 
for (int i = 0; i < _supportedHttpMethodsByConvention.Length; i++)
{
    if (methodInfo.Name.StartsWith(
        _supportedHttpMethodsByConvention[i].Method, 
        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        supportedHttpMethods.Add(_supportedHttpMethodsByConvention[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that POST is the default HTTP Method if nothing else is defined.

You can work out what is going on by browsing through the [Web API 2 source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/main/src/System.Web.Http/Controllers/ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.cs).

Comment: Thanks, it didn't occur to me to look in the code actually. But I'm not sure I want to trawl through it. I understand the verb association, I've been following some of the microsoft tutorials and they use "a convention" for getting all elements which assumes much. I'm just going to expand my answer for reference, but I'll accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

So to expand it seems it's just a convention to return some sort of collection of elements. You can just as happily return a single element, it just maps the parameters, in this case 0.

For the GetAllMyModels case I tried various alternatives and it resolves the following.

GetAllMyModels - Yes
GetMyModels - Yes
MyModels - No
GetHorses - Yes

So the answer appears to be that if the signature starts with Get and has a signature that returns an IEnumerable* and EntityType matches the type used on other controller methods AND it has no parameters then it is used as the method that returns all entities.

*My side case where the return type is an enumerable instead of IHttpActionResult is shorthand. It is equivalent to a return type of IHttpActionResult and returning Ok(the values).