# Calling any method produces the results of the Get() instead of their methods

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

This is probably a badly worded question and this is my first web api so I could be doing something completely wrong.  I have my Controller and my Model, in my Controller I have 3 methods, string[] Apples string[]Get Judgment GetJudgmentByStateCaseId.  I'm trying to call of of them using the following urls but all of the results come from Get() data.

- /api/judgment
- /api/apples
- /api/GetJudgmentByStateCaseId

`JudgmentController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebApplicationsWData.Models;

namespace WebApplicationsWData.Controllers
{
    public class JudgmentController : ApiController
    {
        public string[] Apples()
        {
            return new string[]
            {
                "as","B"
            };
        }

        public string[] Get()
        {
            return new string[]
            {
                "as","C"
            };
        }


        public Judgment GetJudgmentByStateCaseId(string State, string CaseId)
        {

            Judgment judgement = new Judgment
            {
                CaseId = "1",
                State = "MeVMe"


            };
            if (judgement == null)
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            return judgement;

        }




    }
```

`Judgment.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    namespace WebApplicationsWData.Models
    {
        public class Judgment
        {
            [Required]
            public string State { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public string CaseId { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

And here is my `RouteConfig`

```
namespace WebApplicationsWData
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35344367/304683)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so this question should be worded How to support multiple methods for asp api.   I wanted multiple get methods, so essential this post here was the answer `

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/832045/Implementing-a-Basic-REST-Based-ASP-NET-Web-API-Se

And yep it works now :)